# Inserting data into wordpress table using a html form

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am trying for hours to resolve what I thought was a simple issue but am still no further...

Below is my code to input 3 fields into a wordpress custom table called 'std'. Not sure if it is a connection issue or my code is just wrong! when I click submit, the I am just given the "databse insertion failed" message but am not the wiser as to why.

```
<?php

   /*
   Template Name:ProRata
   */

   //get_header();

    if($_POST['Submit']){


    global $wpdb;

    require_once('wp-config.php');

    $name=$POST['aname'];
    $roll=$POST['aroll'];
    $dept=$POST['adept'];

    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'std';

    if($wpdb->insert(
    $tablename,

    array(


    'name'=> $name,
    'roll'=> $roll,
    'dept'=> $dept
    )


    ) ==false) wp_die('databse insertion failed');
    else echo 'Database insertion completed</p>';

    ?>
    <?php
    }
    else // if form has not yet been submitted
    {
    ?>
    <br>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <label>Leave: Type of leave </label>

    <label> aname </label>
    <input type="text" name="aname"><br><br>
    <label> Leave: Start Date </label>
    <input type="text" name="aroll"><br><br>
    <label> Leave: End Date </label>
    <input type="text" name="adept"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit"><br>

    </form>
    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to include `wp-config.php`. You can check the last run query by `$wpdb->last_query`. It will give you an idea of what you are doing wrong.

Comment: thanks for taking a look! wp-config was used to test if it was a db issue----should have removed it in this post. $wpdb->last_query is giving me the following which I do not think is related (could be wrong)... SELECT option_value FROM wpob_options WHERE option_name = 'wppb_private_website_settings' LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will totally resolve your issue, but you are missing the underscores (`_`) when you are storing the `$_POST` values. You need to change those lines to the following:

```
$name=$_POST['aname'];
$roll=$_POST['aroll'];
$dept=$_POST['adept'];
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Justin. I have corrected the underscores but alas, still not resolved...

Answer (score 0):

finally got the answer....

```
Change this
$name=$POST['aname'];
$roll=$POST['aroll'];
$dept=$POST['adept'];

$tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'std';

With this
$name=$_POST['aname'];
$roll=$_POST['aroll'];
$dept=$_POST['adept'];

$tablename = 'std';
```

Error on insertion is because it's trying to insert into table "wp_std", assuming that the prefix on your wordpress is wp_, or any prefix. Also I changed $POST with $_POST, because even if insertion where true, it would insert empty values because $POST doesnt exists unleast you declare it, correct global variable is $_POST